# Check if property is decorated with specific annotation - Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How can I determine if a specific property is decorated with a specific annotation?

For example this class:

```
class A {
    @DecoratedWithThis
    thisProp: number;
}
```

How can I know that `thisProp` is decorated with `DecoratedWithThis`?

My use case: I use the class from another file to generate code and HTML for the properties.

Could you imagine of another solution?

Comment: Show please `@DecoratedWithThis`. I think you can check through class A. Like this: `if (A.thisProp.__customMetaData) {}`

Comment: `@DecoratedWithThis` is just some function working as the decorator.
`function DecoratedWithThis(target: any, key: string) {
      //doing some stuff like getter setter
 }`

Comment: @OPV unfortunately, this won't work. there isn't any _customMetaData property available

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no native way that I know of in typescript, but there is a way to do it using 'reflect-metadata' library https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata which is a proposed extension to native reflection api.

Decorators are just functions that get executed when your class is defined. in your case you want to create a property decorator

```
function (target, propertyKey) {}
```

Where **target** is your Object.prototype and **name** is the property name

Per **Reflect Metadata Documentation**

```
// define metadata on an object or property
Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, metadataValue, target, propertyKey);

// get metadata value of a metadata key on the prototype chain of an object or property
let result = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, target, propertyKey);
```

You can solve your problem by adding metadata to your property that you can read later on to check if that property has been decorated.

**Example Implementation**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

const metadataKey = 'MyDecorator';

function MyDecorator(target, propertyKey) {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, true, target, propertyKey);
}

function myDecoratorUsingClass<T>(type:  Type<T>, propertyKey: string) {
    return myDecoratorUsingInstance(new type(), propertyKey);
}

function myDecoratorUsingInstance<T>(instance: T, propertyKey: string) {
  return !!Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, instance, propertyKey);
}

class MyClass {
   @MyDecorator
   property1;
   property2;
}

console.log(myDecoratorUsingClass(MyClass, 'property1')); // true
console.log(myDecoratorUsingClass(MyClass, 'property2')); // false

const instance = new MyClass();
console.log(myDecoratorUsingInstance(instance, 'property1')); // true
console.log(myDecoratorUsingInstance(instance, 'property2')); // false
```

**NOTE** To use *myDecoratorUsingClass* your class should have a constructor where all the parameters are optional (or no parameters)

Comment: seems to be the best way atm to do this

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment as a new user I'm posting this as a new answer, although it's just an upgrade of @h0ss answer.

Instead of `!!Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, instance, propertyKey)` you can use `Reflect.hasMetadata(metadataKey, target, propertyKey)` or `Reflect.hasOwnMetadata(metadataKey, target, propertyKey)` as described here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata#api

Comment: thanks a lot. I think they extended the reflect-metadata API recently, so it can be handled way easier now