# Check if class decorator is present in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to check if a class decorator is present for certain types?

If i have a registry, for example, to register several types, i'd like to verify not only the base type but also, if a decorator is present (aka required). Can this be achived somehow?

Take this simple example:

```
abstract class ExpectedBaseType {
  constructor(params: any) {}
}

type ExpectedBaseConstructor = {
  new (params: any): ExpectedBaseType;
}

/** Special decorator */
function Special(value: string) {
  return function <T extends ExpectedBaseConstructor>(ctor: T) {
    console.log('@Special defined on', ctor);
  }
}

class Registry {
  // How to assure, that only @Special-decorated types are used?
  register(special: typeof ExpectedBaseType) {
    console.log('Does special is decorated with @Special?', special);
  }
}
```

Now with concrete usage:

```
@Special('some-value')
class ConcreteSpecialType extends ExpectedBaseType {
  constructor(params: any) {
    console.log('Created concrete special');
  }
}


class ForgottenSpecialType extends ExpectedBaseType {
  constructor(params: any) {
    console.log('Created forgotten special');
  }
}
```

Expectation:

```
const reg = new Registry();
// should be allowed
reg.register(ConcreteSpecialType);
// should not be allowed
reg.register(ForgottenSpecialType);
```

Comment: It isn't, but a common workaround is to use an interface that must be implemented when you use the decorator like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQLBN).

Comment: You can try `reflect-metadata` library, as described here (though for property decorators, not class decorators): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170130/check-if-property-is-decorated-with-specific-annotation-typescript

Comment: @mbojko That won't have any effect at compile-time, though.

Comment: Decorators don't give you the functionality you want, and the implementation of decorators in TS4.9 and below is experimental and due to change soon.  So maybe you can work around this by giving up on decorators and just call a function directly to produce your class, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1YlW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, pls mention @jcalz to notify me)